# IIS 7 windows server 2008 Bad request

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a simple web form on IIS 7 which was working fine. We had to change the password for the service account for the box and all of a sudden the website would not work. Initially I was getting a http 500 error. However after tinkering with the settings i have managed to get an equally unhelpfull error message called "Bad Request". I tried everything online to resolve the issue but I am not able to. Basically I am not able to see a corresponding error message in any logs.

Http logs hve no rows corresponding to my timestamp and IIS logs are empty. I dont know where to go from here. If you need any additional information do let me know. I am attaching the request and response from fiddler trace if it helps

Request
    GET /Adv_Form.aspx HTTP/1.1

Response
    HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Comment: Switch on FailedRequest Tracing and see who generates the error.

Comment: To enable failed request tracing I need to see web server IIS roles in my server manager. In my case the roles are empty and I dont seem to have an option to add new roles. I am using this link to enable this http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/tracing/tracefailedrequests

Comment: You roles are empty? Sure, that your IIS is installed and setup? you can query that with powershell: Get-WindowsFeature

Answer (score 0):

As it will be near impossible for anyone on here to provide the answer to this question regarding a bad request with jsut those two request strings here is what you should do:

There are a few log files you should check:

**IIS Logs: c:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC (then SiteID)**

As you note these are empty so onto:

**HTTPERR Logs: c:\windows\system32\LogFiles\HTTPERR**

These may hold the details around your 400 bad request error.

**ASP.NET Execeptions in the Application Event Log**

You can follow the guide here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749408.aspx on how to use the event view.

Comment: So I tried IIS logs the folder is empty. As for httperr the file does not have anything on the error I am facing if i go by the time stamp and last modified time. Event log also I am not able to see anything at all. These are the general things I tried before as well. I just dont know where I am going wrong with this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding an `error page` in `IIS` that runs a `CF script` (You could use ASP or PHP) called 400.cfm which redirects the user and sends me an email for debugging.

Adding the &400 param to the redirect is to avoid looping.

```
cflocation url="#cgi.HTTP_REFERER#&400" addtoken="no"
```